# SQL find items with max date

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
uid   |     name     |   date
------+--------------+-------------
100   | Sergey       | 2007-07-17
2     | Alexey A.    | 2019-06-20
100   | Sergey A.    | 2017-05-13
2     | Alexey       | 2016-05-03
```

As you can see, each name has got it's unique id, but name fields are different. What I want is to find fields with the same uid, take the field which has a bigger date and write it to the result. The result should look like this:

```
uid   |     name     |   date
------+--------------+-------------
2     | Alexey A.    | 2019-06-20
100   | Sergey A.    | 2017-05-13
```

I understand that I should use basics methods of SQL like group by, max, etc but it's a little bit complicated for me now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date)
                from t t2
                where t2.uid = t.uid
               );
```

Comment: Wouldn't that give extra results if Alexey has one row where its date is the max date of Sergey, without beeing it Alexey's max date? Could that be fixed duplicating the "inner where condition" ( `where t2.uid = t.uid` ) also in the outer clause? Or am I rethinking it too much?

Comment: @DIe . . . The correlation clause ensures that the maximum date is limited only to each `uid`.

Comment: I get it now, thanks, I saw it with sleepy eyes I guess